# Can jboss-web.xml have access to properties?

Tags: maven, jboss, properties, pom.xml, virtual-hosts

I am trying to setup my project to use different virtual-host names depending on the environment.

I know I could create directories with a separate jboss-web.xml file in each directory.  But I recently moved this project to maven and wanted to take advantage of the profiles.  I already have the databases set up so they can be configured differently by the profile by using filters.

jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <virtual-host>${jbossweb.virtualhost}</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

The environment specific property file has an entry for:

```
jbossweb.virtualhost=hostname.domain.com
```

the pom file build section has this definition

```
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/filter-${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Just for good measure, the profiles section has this configuration:

```
  <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
      <env>dev</env>
    </properties>
  </profile>
```

I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.  When I try it, Jboss-web.xml has the variable name in the virtual-host location and not the value.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: It _looks_ like you have all the pieces in place.  Another _slightly different_ approach is to include the value of `jbossweb.virtualhost` in the profile definition.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, I've discovered a way to do this:

The jboss-web.xml looks like this now:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>${jbossweb.contextroot}</context-root>
    <virtual-host>${jbossweb.virtualhost}</virtual-host>
 </jboss-web>
```

The property file looks like this:

```
 jbossweb.virtualhost=hostname
 jbossweb.contextroot=/
```

Then the pom  section looks like this for the maven war plugin configuration:

```
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
                        <targetPath>/WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
```

And the filters are defined above the plug ins section, but within the build section as follows:

```
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/filter-${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
```

Comment: the webResources section is sufficient to enable filtering with maven properties on jboss-web.xml.

Comment: I know this was answered a couple of years ago, so versions may be different; but I was able to get this to work in a Spring Boot project by removing the context-root element from jboss-web.xml and the build picked up the server.context-path from the application.properties file.